# Where can I find the binaries for arm-wince-pe-gcc?

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I am looking for a version of the gcc (C++) compiler targeting the ARM uP and WindowsCE operating system. Thus far I have only been able to locate compilers which either target the ARM uP but produce ELF executables (GNUARM etc) or they do target windows CE but have not been updated since 2003. I believe the exact name of the compiler I am looking for is `arm-wince-pe-gcc` as mentioned In the GCC documentation but I have no clue how to get hold of a binary. Any/all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a binary version of the required compiler here: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=173455&package_id=198682 choose 
0.51.0/cygwin-cegcc-cegcc-0.51.0-1.tar.gz file for download.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using CEGCC from SourceForce: http://cegcc.sourceforge.net/, and so far it works OK. I've managed to build a Windows API application, zlib and libpng, and everything runs just fine on Windows CE 5.0, and the C code you write is the same one you'd write in Visual Studio.

Use the mingw32ce toolchain from there. Build the toolchain yourself, from the latest SVN sources.

I use this under Linux, but it should work under Cygwin as well I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Build one yourself. GCC is well set up to produce cross-compilers, see the [build instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html).